# RTP server for audio stream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ffmpeg, rtp

I'm in the mid of my project where I'm trying to send the audio data over RTP using ffmpeg in VC++.
but I'm unable to do that.
My start up code is:

```
setRTPOutputAddr("127.0.0.1");
    setRTPOutputPort(9985);
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    formatCtx= avformat_alloc_context();

    //av_dump_format(formatCtx,0,"rtp",1);
            avio_open_dyn_buf(&ioctx);
            avio_open(&formatCtx->pb, "rtp", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
            //av_dump_format(formatCtx,0,"rtp",1);
            formatCtx->pb = ioctx;

            rtpCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
            rtpCtx->oformat = av_guess_format("rtp",0,0);
            AVStream *fakeVideo = 0;
            fakeVideo = avformat_new_stream(rtpCtx,0);
            avcodec_get_context_defaults3(fakeVideo->codec, NULL);
            fakeVideo->codec->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS;
            rtpCtx->audio_codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_NONE;
            rtpCtx->video_codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS;
            // avformat_write_header(rtpCtx,0);

            char *url = new char[1024];
            sprintf(url,"rtp://%s:%d",rtpOutputAddr,rtpOutputPort);
            printf("will output to url:%s\n",url);
            avio_open(&rtpCtx->pb,url,AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
            avformat_write_header(rtpCtx, NULL);
            delete url;


            if (avio_open(&formatCtx->pb, "rtp", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s'\n", formatCtx->filename);
        return -1;
    }
            else
            {

            printf("succeed \n");
            }


Error Here:    avformat_write_header(formatCtx, NULL); //program Crashes
```

Do anyone having any idea where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, we have *no* idea what so ever what you're doing wrong. Can you please elaborate on what happens with the code you have? What works? What doesn't work? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Also, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: sorry for the way I asked the question. Some how I'm able to do it and correcting it. I'm trying to stream the audio/video data using RTP the very first I'm checking whether I'm able to write a header or not. and then want to stream encoded audio data. this is a part of my code